# Unable to create a trigger for azure function in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools, azure-triggers

I have been trying to create a function with a http trigger, but unfortunately while creating the azure function, it doesn't show the pop up to choose the trigger point for creating the function, but seeing the function app is created with out init.py file
Attached the screen shot[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Resources Section is used to create the Applications in the Azure Portal through VS Code but not the Triggers directly from VS Code.*

[image]

- If you want to create the Http Trigger or any other Triggers, you have the several ways like VS Code, CLI, PowerShell and Portal in the specified Function App.
- I believe you are using the VS Code, so you’ll have workspace option in the Azure Explorer to create the Function Triggers locally and then deploy to the Azure Function App:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Pravallika.. i was looking the options in resource section